# Django template language shortens words

Tags: django, jinja2, django-multiselectfield

I would like to display the language(s) a user chose for his user profile. 
Everything is working I just can't display the full language name. So when I write `{{user.userprofile.language}}` the html Output is "English, Spanish, French" but when I write `{{user.userprofile.language.0}}` I get "en" instead of "English".

**What I have right now:**

```
<span>En</span>

<span>Fr</span>

<span>Sp</span>
```

**What I would like to have:**

```
<span>English</span>

<span>French</span>

<span>Spanish</span>
```

**Anybody know how to display the full Value?**

EDIT:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    language = MultiSelectField(max_choices=3,choices=settings.LANGUAGES, default='en')
```

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = (
('en', _('English')),
('pt', _('Portuguese')),
('dt', _('Deutsch')),
('sp', _('Spanish')),
('fr', _('French')),
('nl', _('Dutch')),
('pl', _('Polish')),
('au', _('Austrian')),
('ch', _('Schweizerisch')),
('hr', _('Kroatisch')),
('ru', _('Russian')),
)
```

Comment: what is the full value? you are getting english? so?

Comment: im NOT getting "English" I get "en" when I do {{user.userprofile.language.0}} but I Would like to get "English" instead. The User should see the full word not just two letters...

Comment: You haven't shown your models so we have no idea what `userprofile.language` is.

Comment: try {{user.userprofile.get_language_display}}

Comment: @Exprator  same as {{user.userprofile.language}} as soon as I write a number behind it it shows me just one letter. instead of the whole word. so {{user.userprofile.get_language_display.0}} gives me "E" instead of "English"

Comment: dont use 0, just till display

Comment: But then he shows me 3 languages but I only want one. I think I will write some regex with js or split the three values at "," and add them manually in the template. Thanks anyway for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using this [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield) package?

Reading the documentation, it looks like you should be doing something more along the lines of this:

```
{% for code, name in user.userprofile.language %}
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Or perhaps:

```
{% for code, name in user.userprofile.language.choices %}
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Do either of those solutions work for you?

If not, could you please confirm where the `MultiSelectField` in your model was imported from?

Comment: `from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField` yes I use the package multi select but I think its more of a Django thing. Your answer did not work as well. The first code shows just one letter of each language. The second code shows nothing. I made it work with js. Took the string split it and append the word on the page when it loads. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: Strange. I'm not too familiar with that package, so afraid I don't have a better suggestion if that didn't work. At least you got working with JS.